# how divided integer is converted to floating point number with decimal

Tags: java, casting, floating-point

if 123/33 prints out 3 and 3 is an integer if we cast it to float ( (float)123/33 )how do we get the decimal places from the integer 3. does 3 contains floating points internally what ?

```
 public static void test() {
        System.out.println("==========");
        System.out.println(123/33); // prints 3 
        System.out.println((float)123/33); // prints 3.7272727 
        //so if we cast it to float we get the decimal points also (.7272727)
    }
```

Comment: Look at [operator precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/). Operators are evaluated **left to right** and cast has a **higher** precedence than divide. So you are actually doing `((float) 123) / 33`.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna not really a dup - that question is asked by casting the _result_ doesn't work. This question is asking about the precedence of the cast operator.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the accepted anwer of the question I linked explains also the precedence and how the cast works. IMHO this is a dup. Let's see what the rest of the community thinks, I may be wrong after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast does not apply to the entire expression `123/33`. You're casting the value `123` to a float, which causes any further operations to use floating-point math.

Answer (score 1):

`123` will be `casted`(converted) to `float` and then the division happens, so the result will be float value.

```
System.out.println("==========");
System.out.println(123/33); // prints 3 
System.out.println((float)123); // prints 123.0 
System.out.println((float)123/33); // prints 3.7272727
```